# How to return the response from an Ajax live search using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to query an SQL server to auto-populate the search results without reloading the page. I have a search box with a drop down list of options to choose from and i want to show the similar data with the searching value.

I pass the whole database table from controller to the view with simple some simple html for client side dressing and use ajax to pass the search value back to the controller

```
<div class="container">
    <b>Search By : </b>
    <select id="SearchBy">
        <option value="errormsg">errormsg</option>
        <option value="StackTrace">StackTrace</option>
    </select><br /><br />
    @Html.TextBox("Search")<input type="submit" id="SearchBtn" value="Search" /><br /><br />
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="24%">ErrorId</th>
                <th width="4%">errordate</th>
                <th width="24%">Url</th>
                <th width="24%">StackTrace</th>
                <th width="24%">errormsg</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="DataSearching">
            @foreach (var x in Model)
            {
                <tr class="table-success">
                    <td>@x.ErrorID</td>
                    <td>@x.errordate</td>
                    <td>@x.Url</td>
                    <td>@x.StackTrace</td>
                    <td>@x.errormsg</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<script src="/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#SearchBtn").click(function () {
            var SearchBy = $("#SearchBy").val();
            var SearchValue = $("#Search").val();
            var SetData = $("#DataSearching");
            SetData.html("");
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "/Error/Find?SearchBy=" + SearchBy + "&SearchValue" + SearchValue,
                contentType: "html",
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result.length == 0) {
                        SetData.append('<tr style="color:red"><td colspan="3">No Match</td></tr>')
                    }
                    else {
                        $.each(result, function (index, value) {
                            var Data = "<tr>" +
                                "<td>" + value.ErrorID + "</td>" +
                                "<td>" + value.errordate + "</td>" +
                                "<td>" + value.Url + "</td>" +
                                "<td>" + value.StackTrace + "</td>" +
                                "<td>" + value.errormsg + "</td>";
                            SetData.append(Data);
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    })
</script>
```

This method is for receiving the search value and comparing it with the database to return a similar value to the view:

```
public JsonResult GetSearchingData(string SearchBy, string SearchValue)
        {
            List<tblerror_msg> ErrorList = new List<tblerror_msg>();
            if(SearchBy == "errormsg")
            {
                try
                {
                    String errormsg = SearchValue;
                    ErrorList = db.tblerror_msg.Where(x => x.errormsg == SearchValue || SearchValue == null).ToList();
                }
                catch (FormatException)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} Is Not an Error Message", SearchValue);
                }
                return Json(ErrorList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            else
            {
                ErrorList = db.tblerror_msg.Where(x => x.StackTrace.StartsWith(SearchValue) || SearchValue == null).ToList();
                return Json(ErrorList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

When I search for a value the table disappears and nothing is returned. I'm new to jquery/ajax so I'm not sure how to debug if there's no errors, 
how do I return a response from my ajax method?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you are supposed to use the 'keyup' JavaScript event because you want live search. 
Secondly change the JsonResult to ActionResult and return the same Json array.
Furthermore, you are missing a closing tag in the else block if I am not wrong. It would be much better to use a helping model as follows:

```
public class SearchDetailsModel {
    public string SearchValue { get; set; }
    public string SearchBy { get; set; }
}
```

And pass an instance of the object SearchDetailsModel as a parameter to the

```
GetSearchingData(SearchDetailsModel model) { }
```

In the ajax post method do the following

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('SearchValue', Search);
formData.append('SearchBy', SearchBy);
```

and inside in add:

```
data: formData,
```